# How to add configuration (e.g. environment variables) for jupyter notebook server in kubeflow

Tags: configuration, jupyter-notebook, kubeflow

Currently I'm using kubeflow v0.7 and when I create a new Jupyter notebook server, there is a configuration section, but I can't select or add any configurations there. Is there any place that I can add configurations for a new notebook server? Or do I have to include anything I need in the image (which is not ideal for my case)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

OK found something in the [official docs](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/notebooks/setup/)

> Specify one or more additional configurations as a list of PodDefault labels. To make use of this option, you must create a PodDefault manifest. In the PodDefault manifest, you can specify configurations including volumes, secrets, and environment variables. Kubeflow matches the labels in the configurations field against the properties specified in the PodDefault manifest. Kubeflow then injects these configurations into all the notebook Pods on this notebook server.

Also, here is the [PodDefault doc](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/blob/master/components/admission-webhook/README.md). It looks like Kubeflow is using PodDefault to inject those configurations (e.g. environment variables).

Edited: I tried PodDefault and it works perfectly. For people who want more detailed docs about PodDefault, you can check [PodPreset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#podpreset-v1alpha1-settings-k8s-io) which is basically the same.